# Add Multiple Images as Inline Attachment in Email Message Body

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add multiple png images as inline attachments to email body. My email body only has the last image. Looks like the memorysteam was overwritten new one. I tried to use AlternateView as this post suggested [How to attach multi images in email body in windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318788/how-to-attach-multi-images-in-email-body-in-windows-application). But it does not show any image. How to add multiple images attachments? Thanks.

```
struct Webpage
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Img { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CollectTime { get; set; }
}
```

//

```
static void SendMultileImgsWEmail(List<Webpage> msg)
{

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mailserver);
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(From);
    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
    mailMessage.Subject = "xxx";

    foreach (Webpage item in msg)
    {
        byte[] image = item.Img;
        Attachment att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(item.Img), item.SiteName);
        att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
        att.ContentId = item.Id;
        att.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
        mailMessage.Body += "Website Name: " + item.SiteName + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        mailMessage.Body += "Screenshot Time: " + item.CollectTime + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        mailMessage.Body = String.Format( @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", att.ContentId);
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(att);

    }

    //send message

    try
    {

        client.Send(mailMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe the following issue will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358534/send-inline-image-in-email

Comment: Never mind. My last mailMessage.Body was missing concatenate + . That why it only had the last image.